# No particle button available (EVEN WITH MESH)

Tags: particles, error

[image]

created a brand new mesh object, still can't use particles. I've tried every mode and such and it WONT let me use particles. Please help.

Comment: Yes it will, you just can't see the button

Answer (score 1):

Your particle button is off the side of the screen due to the size of your properties window. You can reach the particles button by scrolling over the properties buttons, or expanding the properties window so the entire thing fits at once.

Comment: I just slammed my forehead on the desk so hard it fractured my skull. I can't believe I'm such a colossal idiot. This issue put a halt on a 2 hour project -.- THANK YOU!

Comment: If that solved you issue, can you please mark the answer as accepted? @MattBarbarito